# Building Angular 5 project with CLI

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Hi I have an angular 5 project. I have a doubt regarding the production building for the project. Previously i was not using CLI, so i used gzip in my build. So the server will look at the gzip and load the files for faster loading. I read that Angular 5 now have build optimization by default. I see the largest js file is almost same size as my normal gzip file (main file). Is there any point to do gzip if am using Angular CLI (v1.5)? 
Another question is, If I do ng eject and take out the webpack.config.js then if I do ng build is that webpack.config.js is loading or any other under the hood webpack config file? Bit confused. Can someone help me on this doubts. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, you should of course still activate gzip compression. The download size will become 5 times smaller.

Comment: how to do that JB?

Comment: But then no use of build optimizer from CLI

Comment: How to do that: by reading the documentation of the server you're deploying to. You did it before, so you should already know. And yes, the build optimizer is still useful: it reduces the size of the code, too.

Comment: Sorry JB, i did it in frontendside. Not in server